# How to add UUID to disk image file partition table (.img)

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

Currently I am creating a disk image file (using mtools and parted) which includes grub, a file system and boots a linux kernel.

The grub.cfg I use for it looks like this:

```
insmod part_gpt

menuentry "test image" {
         linux (hd0,gpt1)/bzImage.efi root=/dev/sda1 console=tty console=ttyS0,115200 primary
         initrd (hd0,gpt1)/fs.cpio.gz
}
```

But this always assumes that the device (hd0,gpt1) is the correct device. This is why I would like to add a UUID to the img file so that the boot device can always be the same.

How do I add a UUID to the partition table? I can not use root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

GPT partition tables already have one. Your root filesystem has one, too. Run `blkid disk.img` to list them – it'll show filesystem UUIDs as `UUID=` and partition UUIDs as `PARTUUID=`.

Unfortunately, it seems current GRUB versions [do not yet support](https://www.mail-archive.com/grub-devel@gnu.org/msg28911.html) using partition UUIDs. When the support is added it'll be available under the `search.partuuid` command.

Meanwhile you will probably have to use a filesystem UUID instead:

```
search.fs_uuid --no-floppy --set=root e9ad79d7-...-e3c445c7f4e9
```

Now you can reference paths as `($root)/bzImage.efi` or simply by `/bzImage.efi` because $root automatically applies to all path references.

---

Don't forget to update the Linux `root=` parameter accordingly. When using an initramfs, it needs to be a format that your initramfs understands. (When *not* using an initramfs, the only option is `root=PARTUUID=`.)

Comment: Every time the disk image is generated the UUID will change though, right? I've read up about the mlabel function having  -N (serial) option, will making that one fixed make the FS have the same UUID every time? I guess I could also make the build script run blkid every time and change grub.cfg accordingly..